# Category product->getProductUrl() is really slow

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-list

I just got done diagnosing and (hopefully) resolving an issue with a really slow category listing for a client. After doing some debugging I discovered calling `product->getProductUrl()` in a foreach loop of the `/catalog/product/list.phtml` template was causing major slow downs. Has anyone seen this before? The site is fairly large, many thousands of sku's, hundreds of attributes, hundreds of categories.

The solution for now (I'm not sure how sane this is...) was to change the `product->getProductUrl()` call to `"/" . Mage::getResourceSingleton ('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue ($_product->getId(), 'url_path', Mage::app()->getStore());` which brought a typical cached category load time down from ~5 seconds to ~2 seconds.

How is this working so much better?

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between what you did and what `getProductUrl` does. `getProductUrl` also looks at the current category you're in and adds that to the URL.

For example, your URL will be `/pan.html`. Whereas the slower `getProductUrl` can be something like `/kitchen-appliances/pan.html`, depending on which category you're looking at at that moment.

There's a bunch more stuff that it does, but you might not need it.

Your solution looks decent, except that it can sometime bail if URL rewrites aren't up-to-date (the `getProductUrl` method will then switch to a different URL structure, like `/catalog/product/view/id/4`, but yours will return a 404).

Also, instead of doing `"/" . Mage...` use `Mage::getUrl` instead.

It looks kinda hacky to me and personally I would look at other means to improve the performance instead of doing what you did. I would probably look at block and FPC cache (check out Lesti_Fpc), maybe give the box more resources or maybe investigate further why the call is taking so long. I'm guessing (rough guess) the `core_url_rewrite` has become massive and that's why the `getProductUrl` call is taking so long. Maybe look at ways to make it smaller or maybe truncate it and reindex URL's (on a dev box) and measuring the result. Basically, I don't think `getProductUrl` IS the problem **itself** but that something else is causing the slow call.

Apart from that, can't actually see anything wrong with it, but maybe someone else can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. The core_url_rewrite is massive on this store, so maybe that is it? I was figuring something was missing from the flat catalog. I'm not sure a FPC is better than actually fixing the root cause of the issue in this case. product->getProductUrl() taking 2 extra seconds on a smallish category is a root issue that needs solving, FPC aside.

Comment: Yeah, that can definitely be it. You can measure the difference with the table with the original data and a truncated/reindexed version of it on a test environment for example. There are a lot of resources on the web about that table and reasons why it gets so big (maybe you have a lot of legacy rewrites that can safely be removed while taking SEO into account). I agree you should fix the root problem. It's just that Magento doesn't scale that great for stores with tons of SKU's and you'll have to make it more complex to have it scale well (Varnish/FPC/various caches, etc).

Comment: Great insight, thank you. They are running on a decent server (8 CPU, 16GB RAM) with nginx, mariadb, php 5.6 via php-fpm, redis as the cache backend, etc. FPC's and Varnish have been worked with but have never been quite the right solution for this particular client. I bet addressing their core_url_rewrite is going to be an excellent solution.